# How could I open multiple instances of my Android app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest, intentfilter

I'm building an Android app and one of its functionalities is that it open sites inside it and my app permits the user to create icons for these sites, just like when you add an icon for some site in your desktop with Chrome.
But when you do it with Chrome, for progressive web app, it opens them each one in one instance of the browser and I'd like to do exactly the same thing with my own app.

This is the intent for the shortcut:

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(context, WebActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, appName);
    shortcutIntent.putExtra("app_url", appUrl);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
```

This way, it open a new task each time I click a shortcut but what I really need if that it opens a new task only if there isn't any task running THAT site in the background.

How can I detect this and workaround to open the task from the background or launch a new task?

Comment: you cannot do it. you can open different activities

Comment: Again, Chrome does exactly what I'm trying to do with Progressive web apps shortcuts. Is it a private functionality that Google only provides to its apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured a way to do it. I created an activity to manage the problem, looking to the background tasks and its base intents for a param in extras. This activity has no XML. It only redirects to the right place.
Here is the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;

public class WebAppManagerActivity extends Activity {

    private String appUrl;
    private String appName;
    private String iconUrl;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        appUrl = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("app_url");
        appName = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("app_name");
        iconUrl = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("icon_url");

        ActivityManager.AppTask task = getRunningTask();

        if (task != null) {
            task.moveToFront();
        } else {
            Intent launchActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
            launchActivity.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            launchActivity.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, appName);
            launchActivity.putExtra("app_name", appName);
            launchActivity.putExtra("app_url", appUrl);
            launchActivity.putExtra("icon_url", iconUrl);
            launchActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
            launchActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            WebAppManagerActivity.this.startActivity(launchActivity);
        }

        finish();
    }

    private ActivityManager.AppTask getRunningTask() {

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            return null;
        }

        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        for (ActivityManager.AppTask task : manager.getAppTasks()) {
            if (task.getTaskInfo().baseActivity.toString().contains("WebViewActivity") && 
                    appUrl.equals(task.getTaskInfo().baseIntent.getExtras().getString("app_url"))) {

                return task;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```